# Using pycord and tkinter together returning error

Tags: python, tkinter, discord.py, pycord

RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'send' was never awaited self.tk.mainloop(n) RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

I keep getting the above error on my pycord code. I can't figure out why and have looked at multiple discussions.

Here is the code.

```
root = Tk()
frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frm.grid()
server = StringVar()
channel = StringVar()
text = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(frm, textvariable=server)
e1.grid(column=0, row=0)
e1.insert(0, 'Server')
e2 = Entry(frm, textvariable=channel)
e2.grid(column=0, row=1)
e2.insert(0, 'Channel')
e3 = Entry(frm, textvariable=text)
e3.grid(column=0, row=2)
e3.insert(0, 'Text')

async def send():
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        if guild.name == server.get():
            for channel1 in guild.channels:
                if channel1.name == channel.get():
                    await channel1.send(text)

ttk.Button(frm, text="Send", command=send).grid(column=0, row=4)

def run():
    bot.run('token')

t = threading.Thread(target=run)

def start():
    t.start()

ttk.Button(frm, text="Run", command=start).grid(column=0, row=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `channel1.send(text)` should be `channel1.send(text.get())`. Remove the `async` before the `def send`. Also not really important but you don't need the `StringVar`s as you can directly get the text inside an entry using `<tk.Entry>.get()`.